# What version of rusqlite should I use?

Tags: sqlite, rust, rust-cargo

I'm learning the rust language. So, I try to build a simple web app using sqlite3. But it gets multiple packages link error.
I saw some solution for this error(ex. [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/eev3kh/multiple_packages_link_to_native_library_how_to/)), but they didn't work.
The cause seems to be that the version specification of `rusqlite` is wrong, but I don't know the correct version specification.
How should I configure the `cargo.toml`?

Source codes are here.
`cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "todo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4.0.0-beta.3"
actix-rt = "2.2.0"
thiserror = "1.0.29"
askama = "0.10.5"
rusqlite = { version = "0.23", features = ["bundled"] }
r2d2 = "0.8.9"
r2d2-sqlite3 = "0.1.1"
```

`main.rs`

```
use actix_web::{get, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, ResponseError};
use thiserror::Error;
use askama::Template;
use r2d2::Pool;
use r2d2_sqlite3::SqliteConnectionManager;
use rusqlite::params;

struct TodoEntry {
    id: u32,
    text: String,
}

#[derive(Template)]
#[template(path = "index.html")]
struct IndexTemplate {
    entries: Vec<TodoEntry>,
}

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum MyError {
    #[error("Failed to render HTML")]
    AskamaError(#[from] askama::Error),
}

impl ResponseError for MyError {}

#[get("/")]
async fn index() -> Result<HttpResponse, MyError> {

    let mut entries = Vec::new();

    entries.push(TodoEntry {
        id: 1,
        text: "First entry".to_string(),
    });
    entries.push(TodoEntry {
        id: 2,
        text: "Second entry".to_string(),
    });

    let html = IndexTemplate { entries };
    let response_body = html.render()?;

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok()
        .content_type("text/html")
        .body(response_body))
}

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), actix_web::Error> {

    let manager = SqliteConnectionManager::file("todo.db");
    let pool = Pool::new(manager).expect("Failed to initialize the connection pool.");
    let conn = pool
        .get()
        .expect("Failed to get the connection from the pool.");
    conn.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        text TEXT NOT NULL
        )",
        params![],
    )?
        .expect("Failed to create a table `todo`");

    HttpServer::new(move || App::new().service(index))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

And the error messages are here.

```
error: multiple packages link to native library `sqlite3`, but a native library can be linked only once

package `libsqlite3-sys v0.18.0`
    ... which is depended on by `rusqlite v0.23.1`
    ... which is depended on by `todo v0.1.0 (/Users/******/Documents/IntelliJ project/Rust-project/todo)`
links to native library `sqlite3`

package `sqlite3-src v0.2.9`
    ... which is depended on by `sqlite3-sys v0.12.0`
    ... which is depended on by `sqlite3 v0.24.0`
    ... which is depended on by `r2d2-sqlite3 v0.1.1`
    ... which is depended on by `todo v0.1.0 (/Users/*****/Documents/IntelliJ project/Rust-project/todo)`
also links to native library `sqlite3`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're directly depending on `rusqlite` and using `r2d2-sqlite3` which itself depends on `rusqlite`.

Since `rusqlite` binds to a native library as the message indicates you can't have two versions of rusqlite linking to different versions of sqlite3(-sys), so you need to ensure you use the same version of rusqlite as r2d2.

If you're not going to publish on Cargo, the easiest by far is to leave `rusqlite`'s version as a wildcard (`"*"`), that way the dependency resolver will give you whatever works for `r2d2-sqlite3`. Otherwise you need to check the version of `r2d2-sqlite3` you're using and match it.

Incidentally... r2d2-sqlite3 0.1.1? That seems to be [over 4 years old](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2-sqlite/0.1.1), [the current version](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2-sqlite/versions) seems to be [0.18](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2-sqlite/0.18.0). I'm slightly surprised r2d2 works, though I guess it changes relatively little (0.8.0 was 4 years ago, current is 0.8.9). Though I'm not sure what the utility of r2d2 is for sqlite3, especially for "a simple web app".

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It works! And regarding `r2d2_sqlite`, I made typo `r2d2_sqlite` with `r2d2-sqlite3`. Correct libraly is `r2d2_sqlite`. I use the suggestion of IntelliJ IDE directly without check. Anyway, thanks!